# MVC need to open a dialog box before login for supported browsers warning message with list of browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to open a dialog box containing the list of supported browsers with continue button before login.
Previously I have done it using an xml file containing the list of supported browsers and partial view that displays inside the main login view.

But the login view is overriden for some application. so I decided to use **ActionFilterattribute** to use my own CustomFilterAttribute.

The problem I am getting is I want to redirect to Partial view page having Continue button and containing all supported browsers to show it to the user.
After clicking continue button it should redirects to main view which was originally called.
The code should look like this

```
public class BrowserSupportAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    SupportedBrowsers supBrowser = new SupportedBrowsers(Request.Browser);
    string strSupportedMessage = null;
    if (supBrowser.SupportStatus != SupportStatus.Supported)
    {
        strSupportedMessage = supBrowser.GetMessage();
        //Code here should contain to redirect to specific partial view which contains
          supported browsers list and after redirecting to partial view I want redirect   to the view which was originally called.
    }
}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a RedirectToRouteResult object to the Result property of the filterContext like this:

```
    public class BrowserSupportAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            SupportedBrowsers supBrowser = new SupportedBrowsers(Request.Browser);
            string strSupportedMessage = null;
            if (supBrowser.SupportStatus != SupportStatus.Supported)
            {
                strSupportedMessage = supBrowser.GetMessage();
                filterContext.ActionParameters.Add("message", strSupportedMessage);
                filterContext.ActionParameters.Add("returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url);
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "YOUR_ACTION" }, { "controller", "YOUR_CONTROLLER" } });
            }
        }
    }
```

And the action for the supported browser view.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the supported browser list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">Message for supported browsers.</param>
    /// <param name="returnUrl">The url of the login page.</param>
    public ActionResult YOUR_ACTION(string message, string returnUrl)
    {
        // This is the action to show the view with the supported browsers
        // You can process the ViewBag variables in the view
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @ lasz Thanks for your reply..It will be redirecting to the main view directly..I want to redirect that to Partial view showing the warning message and all supported browser. then a continue button in that partial view should redirect to the original action called. In your example it straightly taking to the view originally called or bypassing the partial view. I am newbie to this MVC anyway..

Comment: This custom attribute I can use it on any logon page(different sites overriding the main logon page) so that it will redirect to Partial view showing all supported browsers and after continue button it should show the view which was originally called by the controller(controller in which the attribute called).. I need the code to redirect to partial view and from that I need to redirect to logonpage which should be generic as we donot know which logon page...I think I have explained well :)...